# How to run a different SQL function when changing to a different page/component in Node.js (React)?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs

First and foremost, I managed to extract the information from SQL using the mssql module along with node.js, express and axios. (server.js)

It works fine when I run both development servers (React:3000, node:5000).

Here's the code for server.js

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.enable('trust proxy');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    const sql = require("mssql");

    //DB configuration object
    const config = {
        user: 'INSERT USERNAME HERE',
        password: 'INSERT PASSWORD HERE',
        server: 'INSERT SERVER NAME HERE',  
        database: 'INSERT DB NAME HERE' 
    };

    //connnecting to DB
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
         //if (err) console.log(err);

        //creates Request object
        const request = new sql.Request();

       //search query string
       const queryString = "INSERT QUERY HERE"

        //query to DB and gets data
        request.query(queryString, function (err, recordset) {

            //to log user ip address (nothing particular)
            console.dir(req.ip)

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            sql.close();
        });
    });
});

const server = app.listen(5000,function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

My question is how do I make the queryString dynamic when I change to a different page or component?

Here's the original table component where I put the information into.

```
import Page from 'components/Page';
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import Result from 'components/Result';
import API from '../routes/api/api';

class TablePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            userList: null
    };
  }
  render() { 

    const { userList } = this.state;
    const tableTypes = ['Report'];
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() -8);
    var today2 = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
      } 
    if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
     }   
     today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

    return (
      <Page
        title={"Completed RFQs" + " " + today + "~" + today2}
        breadcrumbs={[{ name: 'report', active: true }]}
        className="TablePage"
      >
        {tableTypes.map((tableType, index) => (
          <Row key={index}>
            <Col>
              <Card className="mb-3">
                <CardHeader>{tableType || 'default'}</CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Result  userList={userList} />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ))}
      </Page>
    );

  }

  async componentDidMount() {
          try{
        let userData = await API.get('/')
         .then(res => res.data);

         const users = [];
         for (var i in userData.recordsets) {
          for (var j in userData.recordsets[i]) {   
             var x = userData.recordsets[i][j];
             users.push(x)
          }
    }//end for loop 

const userList = users.map((user,index)=>
  <tr key={index}>
  <th scope = "row">{(i++)+1}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.AEG_PERSON_NAMEEN}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.OLDPRDNO}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.PWNO}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.SALES_REF}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.JUM_PTYPE1}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.SALES_PERSON_NAMEEN}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.KEYWORD_ENDUSER}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.REPLIED_DATE.slice(0,10)}</th>
  <th scope = "row">{user.D}</th>
  </tr>);

this.setState({
...this.state, ...{
userList
}
});   
        }
         catch(e){
        console.log(` Axios request failed: ${e}`);
      }
  };
}

export default TablePage;
```

Let's say I am making another page to display different information into the table, how do I run that server.js function with a different query?
Do I really need to make another server2.js as the codes would be redundant?

My ideal way is to just run a different query into the same function when changing to a different page but I just don't know how to do it in a different way other than creating another server2.js.

Answer (score 0):

what excactly you like to query? can you give 2 examples? normaly you can fetch parameters with a route like:

app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res) {

let id = req.params.id
let sqlQuery ="Select USER where id=" + id

}

sry for bad writing and coding, was quick n dirty by smartphone.

but i think i didnt understand the question exactly ;)